# custom json serialization in dynamoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, amazon-dynamodb

I need to write a custom json serializer and deserializer for a model in dynamoid which will be written to DynamoDB.

Copying sample model from https://github.com/Veraticus/Dynamoid#fields:

```
class User
  include Dynamoid::Document

  field :name
  field :email
  field :rank, :integer
  field :number, :float
  field :joined_at, :datetime
  field :another_class, :serialized

end
```

Here `another_class` field is object of some other class (non-primitive). The `another_class` contains some primitives and again some non-primitives. How to achieve the custom json serialization?

**Edit 1:**

We can achieve custom json serialization as mentioned below in my answer, but it's without using `:serialized`.

**Edit 2:**

If we use `:serialized`, it is storing values after serialization but it uses default YAML serializer. I had object of the following class:

```
 class CClass
    attr_accessor :a, :b
 end
```

The value stored after serialization was:

> --- !ruby/object:CClass\na: aval\nb: bval\n

But now I don't want to use YAML serializer. I want to use custom JSON serializer. For e.g. It should store the object in following way:

> {"a-key1":"aval","b-key2":"bval"}

What methods should I override in CClass so that it will use the overridden methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model above, another_class is a string field.
I was in search of a way which would let me assign `another_class` variable with an object of `AnotherClass`. And it would automatically call the serialization methods.

But, I've found a way to achieve the same although by calling those methods ourselves.

So, in AnotherClass class definition, we will need to write two methods:  `to_json(*a)` and `self.json_create(o)` as explained here: http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/

```
class AnotherClass 
  def to_json(*a)
  end

  def def self.json_create(o)
  end
end
```

By calling these two methods as needed, I'll be able to perform the desired task.

**Edit (2014/12/04):**

I realized that calling `JSON.dump(AnotherClass.new)` is invoking `AnotherClass#to_json` method. This applies even when `AnotherClass` object is buried in list in value part of a hash! This is what I was looking for! :)